# jquery star rating

Tags: jquery

I'm using the star rating plugin at http://php.scripts.psu.edu/rja171/widgets/rating.php,

but it always complains:

```
stars.lt is not a function
```

It breaks on this error:

```
stars.lt(settings.curvalue).addClass('on').end();
```

anyone know what's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to your page? I would suspect your javascript file is not present for some reason.

Comment: Or you can use a [much newer jQuery star rating plugin, with HTML5 and touch support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542883/jquery-star-rating/13176213#13176213).

Answer (score 5):

That plugin uses an *extremely* old version of jQuery (over 3 years), the `.lt()` method no longer exists.

You can update the plugin to work though, replace these 2 spots in the file (lines 136 & 144):

- `.lt(index)` with `.slice(0,index)`
- `.lt(settings.curvalue)` with `.slice(0, settings.curvalue)`

That should get you going, [see a working updated version here](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxce/).