# jQuery Star Rating Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone who use jQuery Star Rating Plugin: it is possible to show a label (very poor, etc.), like on this another star rating:

http://orkans-tmp.22web.net/star_rating/

Comment: Add a label div, then on `mouseover` just set the contents of the label appropriately (depending on what star was `mouseover`ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing

here have a look at **Test 3-B**

Answer (score 1):

Add an onHover to your element with an id of #stars-cap

Then put this in your script:

```
$("#stars-wrapper1").stars({
    captionEl: $("#stars-cap")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If mobile/touch support is important to you, check out the [rateit plugin](https://github.com/gjunge/rateit.js) plugin. I've [evaluated star-rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542883/jquery-star-rating/13176213#13176213) and a number of other rating plugins to select one for repackaging for Meteor.js, and `rateit` was the best.

Comment: I am trying to use rateit but have not figured out how to install it properly. Do you know where the image files go? The documentation leaves a lot ot be ddesired.