# jQuery star rating system with partial stars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your advice, google is not helping me out on that one. I need a star rating system for my website BUT it should be capable of displaying an initial value with decimals (2.75 -> displaying 3/4 of a star) and the input should only allow integers. I found no script that combines both features. Do you have any idea?

The best would be a ready-made jquery plugin.

Kind regards,
Quentin

Comment: Maybe the JQuery star rating plugin?  http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. However, [RateIt](http://rateit.codeplex.com/) was the only one that could show me a preset float value in a partial star and rate with a full star:

```
<div class="rateit" data-rateit-value="2.76" data-rateit-step="1" data-rateit-resetable="false" >
```

Answer (score 3):

As you wish:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

Seems to be capable of doing such things.

Comment: `rateit` is superior to this plugin, for reasons I've explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542883/jquery-star-rating/13176213#13176213)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. A list of the [top 10 rating plugins for jquery](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-rating-plugins/) and [this one](http://jvance.com/blog/2008/09/22/JQueryRaterPluginNew.xhtml) in particular for you fractions.

Comment: Been through the list. Every single plugin there is inferior to [rateit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542883/jquery-star-rating/13176213#13176213)

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. Maybe you should give a look [cdn.webdeveloperswall.com/demo/css-star-rating/](http://cdn.webdeveloperswall.com/demo/css-star-rating/)

Answer (score -2):

Use this best star rating plugin..i used it with no issues.
[Raty](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/)

Comment: No, this is not the "best star rating plugin". I know because I've actually compared a bunch of them - see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542883/jquery-star-rating/13176213#13176213).