# jQuery Star Rating using Select Option dropdown

Tags: jquery

I need a little help here... last several hours been trying to figure this out, and getting nowhere.

I found this simple jQuery Star rating system that i'd like to use, the original coding was using an INPUT field but I changed it to being used with a Select Option Dropdown. When it's displayed on the left you have the dropdown and to the right you have the default STARS. Now when you click on the STARS, the dropdown options change... which is good, that part I want to keep, However when you use the actual Dropdown the stars wont change... here is the coding...

```
<select name="my_input" id="rating_simple">
    <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1">Poor</option>
    <option value="2">Below Average</option>
    <option value="3">Average</option>
    <option value="4">Good</option>
    <option value="5">Excellent</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#rating_simple").webwidget_rating_simple({
        rating_star_length: '5',
        rating_initial_value: '',
        rating_function_name: '',
        directory: 'rating-system/'
    });
});
```

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could yu put a jsFiddle together?

Comment: correct your html structure. You not put drop down in body section.

Comment: here is a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JHWebDesigner/F7bjH/ Only problem is on the jsFiddle the stars aren't showing up... look at the demo link above you can see it more in action.

Comment: @JonathanHollins See my answer, added a working fiddle (changed the script code to see the stars, cange it according to your needs)

Comment: There are [much better solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13176213/155813) for simple star rating. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihirgokani007/xd7b5/) for a quick example of [raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any built-in function to set the value; I made up a little script to handle that using the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) select handler:

```
$('#rating_simple').change(function () {
    $(".webwidget_rating_simple > li").css('background-image', 'url(http://www.jhwebdesigner.com/rating-system/rating-system//nst.gif)')

    $(".webwidget_rating_simple > li").slice(0,this.value).css('background-image', 'url(http://www.jhwebdesigner.com/rating-system/rating-system//sth.gif)')

});
```

I set to no starred all the option, and then with the [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method set to starred the selection.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eeG86/

**Important note**: to let the fiddle works, I changed the script code to see the stars, change the code according to your needs

For completeness I think this is the project site: http://www.loocasdance.pl/lib/ranking/rating.html

Comment: Edward You ROCK!...haha.. Thanks so much!... I tried something similar to what you wrote but somehow i was getting multiple stars...hahah. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also -

```
$('#rating_simple').change(function(){

        var rating = $(this).val();
        $('.webwidget_rating_simple li').css({
                'background-image' : 'url(http://www.jhwebdesigner.com/rating-system/rating-system//nst.gif)'
            });
        $('.webwidget_rating_simple li:lt('+rating+')').css({
                'background-image' : 'url(http://www.jhwebdesigner.com/rating-system/rating-system//sth.gif)'
            });

    });
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Nyu/

Answer (score 0):

I modified the plugin that wasn't made to listen to select change :

```
(function (a) {
    a.fn.webwidget_rating_simple = function (p) {
        var p = p || {};
        var b = p && p.rating_star_length ? p.rating_star_length : "5";
        var c = p && p.rating_function_name ? p.rating_function_name : "";
        var e = p && p.rating_initial_value ? p.rating_initial_value : "";
        var d = p && p.directory ? p.directory : "images";
        var f = "";
        var g = a(this);
        b = parseInt(b);
        init();
        g.change(function(){var r = a(this).val()-1;f=""; g.next('ul').children('li').eq(r).trigger('mouseenter');f=r+1; g.next('ul').children('li').eq(r).trigger('mouseenter').trigger('mouseleave')});
        g.next("ul").children("li").hover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("li").css('background-image', 'url(' + d + '/nst.gif)');
            var a = $(this).parent().children("li").index($(this));
            $(this).parent().children("li").slice(0, a + 1).css('background-image', 'url(' + d + '/sth.gif)');
        }, function () {});
        g.next("ul").children("li").click(function () {
            var a = $(this).parent().children("li").index($(this));
            f = a + 1;
            alert(f);
            g.val(f);
            if (c != "") {
                eval(c + "(" + g.val() + ")")
            }
        });
        g.next("ul").hover(function () {}, function () {
            if (f == "") {
                $(this).children("li").css('background-image', 'url(' + d + '/nst.gif)').css('background-color', '#0f0')
            } else {
                $(this).children("li").css('background-image', 'url(' + d + '/nst.gif)').css('background-color', '#0f0');
                $(this).children("li").slice(0, f).css('background-image', 'url(' + d + '/sth.gif)').css('background-color', '#f00')
            }
        });

        function init() {
            $('<div style="clear:both;"></div>').insertAfter(g);
            g.css("float", "left");
            var a = $("<ul>");
            a.attr("class", "webwidget_rating_simple");
            for (var i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
                a.append('<li style="background-image:url(' + d + '/nst.gif)"><span>' + i + '</span></li>')
            }
            a.insertAfter(g);
            if (e != "") {
                f = e;
                g.val(e);
                g.next("ul").children("li").slice(0, f).css('background-image', 'url(' + d + '/sth.gif)')
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {

    $("#rating_simple").webwidget_rating_simple({

    rating_star_length: '5',

    rating_initial_value: '',

    rating_function_name: '',

    directory: 'rating-system/'

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7bjH/5/

Added background colors for testing