# Html/CSS Star Rating Feedback

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce, visualforce

I have to implement a Star rating Feedback on articles in Visualforce page . I have seen the code in http://codepen.io/rogie/pen/GIfqc which perfectly suits my requirement . But don't know why it doesn't work when i put the whole code in a file and execute . Also it doesn't work in Firefox . Can anyone help me out here..??

@IamDesai - Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.star-rating{
font-size:0;
white-space:nowrap;
display:inline-block;
width:250px;
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
background:
url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px"     viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve"><polygon     fill="#DDDDDD" points="10,0 13.09,6.583 20,7.639 15,12.764 16.18,20 10,16.583 3.82,20 5,12.764 0,7.639 6.91,6.583 "/></svg>');
background-size: contain;
}
i{
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
z-index: 1;
background: 
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve"><polygon fill="#FFDF88" points="10,0 13.09,6.583 20,7.639 15,12.764 16.18,20 10,16.583 3.82,20 5,12.764 0,7.639 6.91,6.583 "/></svg>');  
background-size: contain;
}
input{ 
-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
opacity: 0;
display:inline-block;
width: 20%;
height: 100%; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
&:hover + i,
&:checked + i{
opacity:1;    
}
}
i ~ i{
width: 40%;
}
i ~ i ~ i{
width: 60%;
}
i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
width: 80%;
}
i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
width: 100%;
}
}


.choice{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
display:block;
}

*, ::after, ::before{
height: 100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;  
vertical-align: middle;
}

body{
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", 
Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
&::before{
height: 100%;
content:'';
width:0;
background:red;
vertical-align: middle;
display:inline-block;
}
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">$(':radio').change(
function(){
$('.choice').text( $(this).val() + ' stars' );
} 
)</script>

</head>
<body>
<strong class="choice">Choose a rating</strong><br>
<span class="star-rating">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code so that we can help you. A jsFiddle would be better.

Comment: @IamDesai - Can u take a look once.. I have added the code above .

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13176213/586051

Comment: So basically you're asking 1) how to put such a feature on the page 2) how to support storage (database) 3) how to store it in that database. 4) do this in visualforce/apex.   It's gonna be a bit more work than copying some code i'm afraid. Unless you already have all of that, which would be nice if you'd update that into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hear is a working fiddle [StarFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grv_bajpai/msLLQ/8/) and you need to include

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Single file do you want this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Star</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<style type='text/css'>
.star-rating {
font-size: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
z-index: 1;
background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
opacity: 0;
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
width: 100%;
}
.choice {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
display: block;
}
*,
::after,
::before {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
body {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
body::before {
height: 100%;
content: '';
width: 0;
background: red;
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(':radio').change(
function(){
console.log(this.value);
$('.choice').text( this.value + ' stars' );
}
)
});//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="star-rating">
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
<strong class="choice">Choose a rating</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try raty plugin for rating .. Read [Documents](http://wbotelhos.com/raty)
and Demo [sample](http://testweb3.iecworld.com/jsdemo/js/lq_js_point/)

Answer (score 0):

You havent included jQuery in your code above. Just add this line to your code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @PruthviRaj Its not working at my side either. I would suggest you to user other plugins mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13176213/586051

Comment: As i have to use incorporate the functionality in Salesforce platform can u suggest me some other than plugins...???

Comment: I need a simple HTML/CSS coded star rating which when clicked stores the rating value in a variable.. Couldnt find which is complete till now... Or may be i couldnt do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  } 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```